# Using a 13.8 VDC 30-50A switching power supply on a 15A house circuit

Tags: power-supply

Want to use a bench top power supply to run 2 - 40Watt motorola radios. What is the max amp rating to use safely on a 15A home circuit?

Answer (score 1):

At a rough guess, the radios will each draw under 5 Amps while transmitting (and well under 1 amp while receiving.)  With both transmitting, that would be 10 Amp at 13.8 Volts.  The power supply will draw a little over 1 Amp at 120 Volts, so there will be no problem powering the system from a 15 Amp home circuit. (and the power supply you suggest is overkill for the task.)

Comment: I am looking at the radio paperwork and it said 13A max at 40 watt. That still puts me in a safe zone. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Considering that a common PS that can put out 13.8VDC @ 30A(con)/50A(int) will have a ~15A fuse, I would say about 25 - 30 amps.
Those figures are taken from both a Alinco desktop PS and rack mount of unknown origins.
Those supplies are both fairly new.  If we are talking about an OLD one, I would cut it down to maybe 13.8VDC @ 20-25A.

Comment: Thank you, I was planning on using a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended power supply for Motorola 25-60W radios is the Motorola HPN4007D.

It's a 13.8V DC 15 A Output Switched Mode Power Supply working off 110-220V AC input.

Your 13.8V DC 30-50A Switched Mode Power supply would be more than adequate to power your two 40W Motorola radios. It would draw only around 5A from the 120V~ utility supply.